# Return first n chars of a string

Tags: go

What is the best way to return first n chars as substring of a string, when there isn't n chars in the string, just return the string itself.

I can do the following:

```
func firstN(s string, n int) string {
     if len(s) > n {
          return s[:n]
     }
     return s
}
```

but is there a cleaner way?

BTW, in Scala, I can just do `s take n`.

Comment: No, Go is not Scala. How is `s take n` "cleaner" than `firstN(s, n)`?

Comment: When you say char, do you mean byte or rune? The code in the question looks good to me if the goal is to return the first N bytes.  A loop is required to return the first N runes.

Comment: @JimB s take n is cleaner because it doesn't require writing a whole new function for a one liner

Comment: @Kaffiene: it's only a one-liner because someone else wrote the `take` function for you. Not all languages will have everything pre-made like that, or have the syntax to fashion expressions in this way.

Comment: @JimB Of course - but Scala DOES have that written for you and having that done for you and not requiring you to write a new function just for this rather trivial task makes your code cleaner.

Comment: @Kaffiene: Go chooses to not include things like this precisely because they are trivial -- it's a language design decision. If you want a `take` function, then you are free to write one, just as you are free to not use Go if it doesn't suit you.

Comment: @JimB I'm not criticising Go. I program in Go. I like Go. It's just trivially true that a language that doesn't require you to implement trivial functions is going to result in cleaner code than one that doesn't. I CAN write taken in asm but choosing something higher level leads to a cleaner solution. Thats not a criticism of asm!

Answer (score 9):

Your code is fine unless you want to work with unicode:

```
fmt.Println(firstN("世界 Hello", 1)) // �
```

To make it work with unicode you can modify the function in the following way:

```
// allocation free version
func firstN(s string, n int) string {
    i := 0
    for j := range s {
        if i == n {
            return s[:j]
        }
        i++
    }
    return s
}
fmt.Println(firstN("世界 Hello", 1)) // 世

// you can also convert a string to a slice of runes, but it will require additional memory allocations
func firstN2(s string, n int) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    if len(r) > n {
        return string(r[:n])
    }
    return s
}
fmt.Println(firstN2("世界 Hello", 1)) // 世
```

Comment: Is there an library for basic string handling methods like this?

Answer (score 3):

```
  college := "ARMY INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY PUNE"
  fmt.Println(college)
 
  name :=  college[0:4]
  fmt.Println(name)
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you) if college consisted of 2 symbols, your code would panic.

Comment: Agree @MariaEfimenko , better to put checks comparing length of string and max bound